# How to get unique elements from ArrayList without clone

Tags: java, arrays, list, hashset

I am trying to make a unique < Integer> ListArrayA from an another < Integer>ListArrayB which is having repeated elements. The ListArrayA and ListArrayB are separately defined. List B is already filled with the data and it having about 10000 Integers in it.

I created a function called unique() and used the following logic. While running this logic, the program is never ending. I wonder it is very simple and small logic bu still this is not working. Is static declaration is a problem?

Basically I want to create a new Array/ArrayList from ListB such that I have unique elements in List A. I don't want to loose List B . I want to keep the List B as it is.

How can I do it? I heard about cloning an another List and then doing basic search to create a new one. I don't to clone(copy) to keep the efficiency.

I also heard about HashSet. But I don't want to clone a copy of List B and I don't want to loose List B content. [List B should be intact as it is]. How can I achieve it?

```
static ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
function unique(){
  a.add(b.get(0));
  for(int i=1;i<b.size();i++){
        for(int m=0;m<a.size();m++){
            if(b.get(i)!=a.get(m)){
                a.add(b.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the HashSet which I though about. But I cannot access the Elements from it.

```
static Set<Integer> uniqueElem;
```

and then in the function call I initiliazed it with:

```
uniqueElem = new HashSet<Integer>(b);
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your reason against a set makes no sense to me. And if you don't know how to access the elements, then read a basic tutorial about sets and how to iterate them

Comment: I loose the order of the elements in the HashSet!

Comment: There are more `Set` implementations, than just `HashSet` ... so look around and you will find one that suits you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the unique elements in the list in O(n) time by stepping through the list, and adding the elements that exist to a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). It could be a `HashMap<Integer,Integer>`, with the second value being the number of times the value occurred, if you do care.

Once you've built the `HashMap`, you can then do look-ups to ask the question "does this element exist" via `HashMap.get(Integer value)`, which will return `null`, if the answer is "no."

Or if you just want to see what the values are, print out the keyset returned via `HashMap.keySet()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying your suggested way. Thank you!

Comment: Technically, that's O(nlogn) - you do a HashMap insert for each element.

Comment: How do you arrive at nlogn?

Answer (score 2):

Will this do?

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(b));
```

Keep in mind that you do not explain your problem or your constraints well.

Comment: Use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) if you want to preserve the original order.